# custom MAIL server -> Proxy Server -> Gmail Server

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, gmail, mx-record

So I have some custom VPS which route emails via MX record in DNS. And I need to setup gmail interface via Google Apps - this step and previous are clear. But how can I insert some middle layer, to check emails messages for special words/etc., so something like spam assasin proxy, but custom product.

The question is:
How could i setup proxy mail from my server => to proxy server(or application) => to gmail servers?

Thank you, for any help!

Comment: I'm just courious why you are putting a spamfilter infront of GMail. AFAIK Google does some excelent spam checking.

Comment: `"which route emails via MX record in DNS"` - is there a different way to route emails? If you already have an MTA then why not filter there - why use an additional component?

Answer (score 0):

Mailscanner can do the checks that you want to perform.

Comment: thanks for response, but I'll need to check each email for *my custom* filters. and I didn't get it, how to setup it before gmail?
because gmail is work via mx-record, so its mean that installed mailscanner or whatever else will not got any mail, isn't it?
so how do I hack this stuff? thanks.

Comment: You cannot do that if you want to do your own checks then you have to get the mx records to point to you. Then you deliver to gmail

Comment: but how do i transfer mail next to gmail server after my proxy to gmail server

Comment: Depends on your proxy, you just need to tell it the final destination is the google server.

Comment: can you give me a sample of such configuration or proxy product url, please?

Comment: sir, please advice a product for this goal?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup what is called a smarthost on your mail server to point to your proxy which would then send the mail out to gmail. I would need to know what mail server you are using to tell you *how* to set this up for your particular mta

Comment: please tell me dear Zypher, my server is running Ubuntu 10.04